# Getting route parameters lararvel livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-livewire

Can someone help me I can't get the routing params when I use inline components for some reason I tried reading the docs but no luck.

My web.php

```
Route::get('/preview/blog/{wow}', BlogPost::class);
```

My BlogPost Class Component

```
    public $wow;

    public function render($wow)
    {
        dd($wow);
        return view('livewire.blog.blog-post', compact('wow'))->layout('layouts.blog');

    }
```

My inline component

```
@livewire('blog.blog-post', ['wow' => $wow])
```

Answer (score 3):

This also works.

```php
Route::current()->parameter('PARAMETER_NAME');
```

Example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Client\Auth;

use Livewire\Component;

class Verify extends Component
{

    public string $token = '';

    public function mount()
    {
        $token = \Route::current()->parameter('token');
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Often you need to access route parameters inside your controller methods. Because we are no longer using controllers, Livewire attempts to mimick this behavior through its mount method. For example:

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', ShowPost::class);

class ShowPost extends Component
{
    public $post;

    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->post = Post::find($id);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer imo

Answer (score -1):

You can access route parameters in livewire with the request passed. This method is useful when you want to use with optional parameters as well `/preview/blog/{wow?}`

```php
Route::get('/preview/blog/{wow}', BlogPost::class);
```

```php
public $wow;

public function mount()
{
   $wow = request()->wow;

}
```